# Accessing variables from constructors in static methods

Tags: php

I have a class with methods, some of these methods use the same variable across board - "$company_id". Now, I don't want to explicitly define what is contained in $company_id for every method. I want to define it once in a constructor and then reference it in my methods. Please how do I do this? This is how it looks currently.

```
public function __construct(){
//what should I do here?
}
    public static function getItemLimit(){
            $company_id = Auth::user()->company_id;
            $item_limit = Company::where('id', $company_id)->count();
            return $item_limit;
        }
        public static function currentItemCount(){
            $company_id = Auth::user()->company_id;
            $item_count = Item::where('company_id', $company_id)->count();
            return $item_count;
        }
```

Comment: how do you instantiate the class? do you do a `$foo = new foo()` or are you using lots of static calls direct like `foo::getItemLimit()`? One approach would be to define `static $company_id` as a class property and reference `foo::$company_id` all over the place, but that could be messy.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question more precisely?

Comment: @Scuzzy I am using lots of static calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Use Company_Id instead of $abcVar

```
class Abc{
public static $abcVar = '';
public function __construct()
{
    self::$abcVar = 11;
}
public static function getItemLimit()
{
    echo self::$abcVar;
    exit;
}
}
$obj = new Abc();
Abc::getItemLimit();
```

Comment: It returns null i.e.  echo self::$abcVar;

Comment: before you call static method you need to create class object so constructor will call and value assign to static variable  ( just copy my code and run in phpfiddle )

Comment: @Maulik ...or you can write up a phpfiddle and add it to your answer.